# no diff output when using "git diff HEAD file.c"

Tags: git

I'm trying to diff the modified file with the latest checked in version and this is the output I see:

```
$ git diff HEAD file.c
diff --git a/path/to/file.c b/path/to/file.c
old mode 100644
new mode 100755
index 5f8af1c..a828cb0
Binary files  a/path/to/file.c and b/path/to/file.c differ
```

I want to see the actual difference, can you please help me look at that?

Comment: It thinks they are binary files. Are they? Have you been editing them in a wordprocessor like Microsoft Word?

Comment: Whats the text encoding for the files? git can get confused with multibyte charicter encodings and think that there binary files.

Comment: Thanks Robin Green and user1937198. The character encoding got messed up while using this particular text editor

Comment: @DriverDev you should post that as an answer, and accept it. That way this question will be marked as resolved and anyone who finds the question will easily be able to find the answer.

Answer (score 0):

The files are treated as binary files, possibly due to the text encoding. Make sure the files are saved with single byte character encoding, if they are indeed text files.